# Using node modules in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, webpack, browserify, node-modules

I am trying to use a third party module which is available as a node module in my angular application. I have just started using angular and I am yet to fully understand the modular behavior.
I am importing the angular modules (router etc) through script tags and injecting them in my main app module but I do not know how to inject the node modules.

Google has got me even more confused with words such as CommonJS, AMD etc. as I am just starting to learn about modular approach.
Can someone guide me on how to inject node modules inside my app module?

I am using AngularJS v1.6.4. I have the option to use browserify and webpack. I have them both.

Comment: You first need to clarify your question by saying if you're using AngularJS (1.x), or Angular (2.x or more), and by telling us how you build your app.

Comment: @JB Nizet I added that detail

Answer (score 8):

After you have installed the module with npm you have to include it with the script tag. Like so

`<script src="node_modules/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js"></script>`

*(I use angular-messages as an example)*

This is typically done in index.html, together with all the other script tags. The path has to be correct of course. It will be from the server point-of-view and Developer Tools will tell you if it can't find the file. You have to inspect the module folder and/or read the module's readme to find what file to use. The actual code you want for most modules is a single .js file.

You can also shorten the path. If you use express it would be done like this

`app.use('/angular-messages', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/angular-messages')));`

and the script tag would change to

`<script src="angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js"></script>`

because express is set up to route *angular-messages* to *node_modules/angular-messages*.

To get the module working in AngularJS you have to add it as a dependency to the app. For example:

`angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute', 'ngMessages']).config(config).run(setupAuth)`

The readme of the module will tell you the name of the module. In this case it was named `ngMessages` so that was added as a dependency. This is typically done in the file where you bootstrap the AngularJS application (app.js or something similar). You can read about how the module function works [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module). The second parameter is usually an array containing the dependency names.

It should be noted that only AngularJS modules are added to this array. If you have a module that is not an AngularJS module, for instance *validator.js*, you have to find some other way to use it. When a script is included in a script tag

`<script src="node_modules/validator/validator.min.js"></script>`

its code will be available in the global *window* object. To access *window* in AngularJS you can use the *$window* service. For instance:

`let isItAlpha = $window.validator.isAlpha('test123'));`

The file validator.min.js gives access to an object called *validator*, which contains a function called *isAlpha*. I could access it by going through *$window*, because the *window* object contained the code read from validator.min.js. This might not be the purest way of using non-AngularJS modules, but it works. Many non-AngularJS modules will also have AngularJS wrappers as separate modules. You could try finding the AngularJS version before trying to use the main version.

I would get it to work this way before using browserify and webpack and all that.

Comment: Is your answer only for Node modules built to be AngularJS modules, or for any Node modules?

Comment: @ThomasDavidKehoe, it doesn't have to be a AngularJS-specific module. For example, the validator.js script I use in the answer looks like [this](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js/blob/master/validator.js) (non-minified), and is not an AngularJS module. Code that is specific for Node will generally not work, because some of the syntax (`require`, etc.) is not supported in the browser. The validator.js library will work both places, because it's written in a generic way.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Not the purest way like you said. But on some legacy projects it does the trick.

Comment: `validator` is working because that library has a `validator.js` file with pure javascript code but what if the library is completely TypeScript based. In that case, how will you import it into the AngularJs controller?