# How to import a class from self-created Angular Library (in node_modules) in Playwright Pages?

Tags: angular, playwright, angular-library

We have an Angular App, where we write our E2E Tests with Playwright using Page Classes. In one of our page classes we need to use/import a class (OptionItem) from a node_module/library we create ourselves; the page class where we have this import looks like this:

```
import { OptionItem } from 'my-ui-components';

export class MyPage {
   .... 
}
```

But while running tests which use this page i get this error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\ui-components\dist\ui-components\fesm2015\ui-components.mjs

    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:948:11)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\my-project\e2e\pages\my.page.ts:6:1)
```

The class OptionItem is defined/exported from an Angular Library Project. And we use this class in our parent Angular App everywhere without a problem. So why does it cause this problem just while running E2E Tests does anybody have any idea?

We also use some other imports from different node_modules in Playright Pages. For example:

```
import { test } from '@playwright/test';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
```

They don't cause any problem. So that's why we think, this has sth. to do with the configuration of the library or the parent project (tsconfig.json, package.json i.e.)

Comment: are you using import in any other part of the playwright framework?

Comment: I edited the question (i dont know why my comment from yesterday is removed...)

Answer (score -1):

According to [the documentation](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3) you've to use the path to the component in the import:

```
import { OptionItem } from '../my-ui-components';
```

So above you've to adjust '../my-ui-components'.

Comment: sorry, but this is not right at all. all node_modules must be imported directly like "import { Subject } from 'rxjs'"; And as i also stated above, i import my type OptionItem in the same way in the whole application, the problem is just in the e2e folder.'
The documentation has '../' because of the their file/folter hierarchy, project structure.

Comment: Maybe this is helping: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46845693/using-node-modules-in-angularjs

Comment: actually that describes another problem.. but thanks.